# Adding a gab in between the ListView

Tags: c#, xml

I can not figure out how can I add a gap in between my list elements so the first three stay at the top and the other two go to the bottom of the slide out bar.

I've heard something about adding a box view in between the elements but wouldn't that make it look different on other devices and OS?

This is the code, I'm using the regular master detail page with some slightly modified elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
         compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="StudyBuddyApp.Components.MainPageMaster"
         Title="Master">

<StackLayout>

<ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">

                <x:String>Profile</x:String>
                <x:String>Forums</x:String>
                <x:String>Find Buddy</x:String>

<!---I want a gap in between these two list items--->

                <x:String>Help and Settings</x:String>
                <x:String>Sign Out</x:String>

            </x:Array>
    </d:ListView.ItemsSource>

    <ListView.Header>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#660066">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="Large"
            TextColor="White"
            Text="StudyBuddy"
            Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>

    </Grid>

    </ListView.Header>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

                <StackLayout Padding="15,10" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        d:Text="{Binding .}"
                        FontSize="24"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Xml format white spaces aren't needed.  You need to add tag data like a comment to have gaps.

Comment: @jdweng could you clarify what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You already have a comment in the xml "I want a gap in between these two list items"  Just leave out the letters.